# Understanding multiple active record joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Seeking an active record wiz to explain what is happening in this join-ception:

```
topic.posts.joins(user: [group_users:[:group]])
```

I get we are looking for a particular topic's, posts and then joining users. Then are we joining user, group_user, and group tables together?

Comment: Run `topic.posts.joins(user: [group_users:[:group]]).to_sql` and you'll see exactly what SQL that query generates.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea and will display exactly the information I am looking for.